# How to read a file and store each word in a array in a array of lines using 2d arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays, file, jagged-arrays

I am trying to read a  text file and then store the words in a 2d array. What I am wanting is to turn this:

```
a b c d e f g
h i j k l m n
o p q r s t u
```

Turns into

`[ [a,b,c,d,e,f,g], [h,i,j,k,l,m,n], [o,p,q,r,s,t,u] ]`

So inside of one array, each line gets its own array and inside of that array each word(in this case only characters) is its own item.

```
        {
            string[] lines = system.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@FilePath);
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                //no idea what to put here
            }
            return contents;
        }
```

Comment: string[][] jaggedArray = lines.Select(x => x.Split(' ')).ToArray();

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution with Linq

```
var result = File.ReadAllLines("C://text.txt").Select(l => l.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)).ToArray();
```

#### Solution with jagged arrays

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("C://text.txt");
var array = new string[lines.Length][];
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
    var line = lines[i].Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    array[i] = line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're wanting an array of word arrays, or `string[][]`

```
// example of what you're reading from the file
var lineArray = new [] {
  "The quick brown fox",
  "Jumped over the lazy",
  "dog from a text file"
};

// 2d array output string[][]
var result = lineArray
  .Select(ln => ln.Split(' '))
  .ToArray();

// result type, should be string[][]
Console.WriteLine(result);

// should be the word "over"
Console.WriteLine(result[1][1]);
```

> Mono C# compiler version 4.6.2.0
>   mcs -out:main.exe main.cs
>   mono main.exe
>   System.String[][]
>   over